# How to add a temporary price change of InAppPurchase with /v1/inAppPurchasePriceSchedules

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, app-store-connect-api

Like Steve with his question, i have problem with this new API :
[Unknown Error trying to add Pricing to a In App Purchase String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73606486/unknown-error-trying-to-add-pricing-to-a-in-app-purchase-string)

I followed Guide from Apple :
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/app_store/in-app_purchase/managing_in-app_purchases

I can change price from inAppPurchase but now i'm stuck with "Promotional Price".

For example, my inApp Puchase have a product tiers 8 at 9.99€ and from 1 November 2022 to 30 November i want a different price (product tiers 4 at 4.99€). The first of December, price will go back to 9.99€.

When testing inAppPurchasePriceSchedules POST, i have 409 error (Conflict) or 500 error.

Here one of payload i test :

```
{
    "data": {
        "relationships": {
            "inAppPurchase": {
                "data": {
                    "id": 1592386688,
                    "type": "inAppPurchases"
                }
            },
            "manualPrices": {
                "data": [{
                        "type": "inAppPurchasePrices",
                        "id": "${prices-id}"
                    }, {
                        "type": "inAppPurchasePrices",
                        "id": "${prices-id-1}"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "type": "inAppPurchasePriceSchedules"
    },
    "included": [{
            "attributes": {
                "startDate": "2022-11-01"
            },
            "id": "${prices-id}",
            "relationships": {
                "inAppPurchasePricePoint": {
                    "data": {
                        "id": "eyJzIjoiMTU5MjM4NjY4OCIsInQiOiJGUkEiLCJwIjoiMyJ9", //Tiers 5
                        "type": "inAppPurchasePricePoints"
                    }
                },
                "inAppPurchaseV2": {
                    "data": {
                        "id": "1592386688",
                        "type": "inAppPurchases"
                    }
                }
            }
        }, {
            "attributes": {
                "startDate": "2022-12-01"
            },
            "id": "${prices-id-1}",
            "relationships": {
                "inAppPurchasePricePoint": {
                    "data": {
                        "id": "eyJzIjoiMTU5MjM4NjY4OCIsInQiOiJGUkEiLCJwIjoiNSJ9", //Tiers 10
                        "type": "inAppPurchasePricePoints"
                    }
                },
                "inAppPurchaseV2": {
                    "data": {
                        "id": "1592386688",
                        "type": "inAppPurchases"
                    }
                }
            },
            "type": "inAppPurchasePrices"
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried with 3 manualPrices, with "{$price1}" or "{$price2}" as id.
I tried with id from current price...

I'm missing something, I must be close by...

## Update

after using Fiddler on appstoreconnect.apple.com and adding / removing promotion i was able to create this payload :

```
{
    "data": {
        "type": "inAppPurchasePriceSchedules",
        "relationships": {
            "inAppPurchase": {
                "data": {
                    "type": "inAppPurchases",
                    "id": "1592386688"
                }
            },
            "manualPrices": {
                "data": [{
                        "type": "inAppPurchasePrices",
                        "id": "${price1}"
                    }, {
                        "type": "inAppPurchasePrices",
                        "id": "${price2}"
                    }, {
                        "type": "inAppPurchasePrices",
                        "id": "${price3}"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "included": [{
            "type": "inAppPurchasePrices",
            "id": "${price1}",
            "attributes": {
                "startDate": null
            },
            "relationships": {
                "inAppPurchaseV2": {
                    "data": {
                        "type": "inAppPurchases",
                        "id": "1592386688"
                    }
                },
                "inAppPurchasePricePoint": {
                    "data": {
                        "type": "inAppPurchasePricePoints",
                        "id": "eyJzIjoiMTU5MjM4NjY4OCIsInQiOiJGUkEiLCJwIjoiNSJ9"
                    }
                }
            }
        }, {
            "type": "inAppPurchasePrices",
            "id": "${price2}",
            "attributes": {
                "startDate": "2022-11-01"
            },
            "relationships": {
                "inAppPurchaseV2": {
                    "data": {
                        "type": "inAppPurchases",
                        "id": "1592386688"
                    }
                },
                "inAppPurchasePricePoint": {
                    "data": {
                        "type": "inAppPurchasePricePoints",
                        "id": "eyJzIjoiMTU5MjM4NjY4OCIsInQiOiJGUkEiLCJwIjoiMyJ9"
                    }
                }
            }
        }, {
            "type": "inAppPurchasePrices",
            "id": "${price3}",
            "attributes": {
                "startDate": "2022-12-01"
            },
            "relationships": {
                "inAppPurchaseV2": {
                    "data": {
                        "type": "inAppPurchases",
                        "id": "1592386688"
                    }
                },
                "inAppPurchasePricePoint": {
                    "data": {
                        "type": "inAppPurchasePricePoints",
                        "id": "eyJzIjoiMTU5MjM4NjY4OCIsInQiOiJGUkEiLCJwIjoiNSJ9"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This one worked !

Thanks

Guldil

Comment: Thanks, even though this was not my exact issue, your example helped me solve an error 500 since I was using "type": "inAppPurchasesV2" instead..